# containerd to graylog

Tags: kubernetes, logging, containerd

I was using /etc/docker/daemon.json to easily configure logs from containers to be sent via UDP to a remote Graylog server and it worked fine.
It's easily achievable with the following config in daemon.json :

```
{
  "log-driver": "gelf",
  "log-opts": {
    "gelf-address": "udp://graylog-server:12201",
    "tag": "staging"
  }
}
```

Recently however, after upgrading a kubernetes cluster, docker engine is no longer available, as it was superseeded by containerd.

- As far as i understand containerd cannot mimic this behavior ? If this isn't true, how can i send logs from containerd to Graylog ?

I have successfully configured fluent-bit as a DaemonSet to send logs to Graylog, however i cannot see the pod/container name in the log message in graylog .

I have tried various guides/docs, lastly i was trying the configuration described here :

https://github.com/microsoft/fluentbit-containerd-cri-o-json-log

I am trying to replicate in any way my previous flow, before moving to containerd :

1. Send logs to graylog (TCP/UDP - both are fine)
2. Have the container/pod name in the log message for search purpouses
3. Add a custom key-value pair in the message metadata, so i can redirect the messages to particular streams, just like i do with 'tag':'staging' in the docker daemon.json exmaple above.